# Android properties file won't load correctly

Tags: android, properties-file

I'm trying to use a properties file to store some properties of my app across restarts. I believe I've followed [this explanation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties) in the Android Developer documentation. Starting with one property, I can see the property being set, stored in a file (config.properties) in my app's internal storage and I can see the file being read when the app starts. However, even though the property was read from the file, it doesn't seem to be loaded by the `Properties` API as I would expect from the [load method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties#load(java.io.Reader)).

Why isn't the property correctly loaded even though it was read from the file?

Here is my code:

A wrapper `MyProperties` class which wraps `java.util.Properties`:

```
public class MyProperties {
    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "propertyName";

    private Properties properties = null;
    private File propertiesFile = null;
    private InputStream inputStream = null;
    private OutputStream outputStream = null;

    public MyProperties(Context context) throws IOException {
        properties = new Properties();
        propertiesFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"config.properties");
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "config file exists: "+propertiesFile.exists());
        propertiesFile.createNewFile();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(propertiesFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(propertiesFile));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Properties file start");
        while(line !=null){
            Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Properties file end");

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(propertiesFile);
        properties.load(inputStream);
    }

    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Fetching property '"+propertyName+"' with value '"+properties.getProperty(propertyName)+"'.");
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public void setProperty(String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Setting property '"+propertyName+"' to '"+propertyValue+"'.");
        properties.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Closing properties");
            properties.store(outputStream, null);
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Exception while closing properties.", ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` class (edited for brevity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "my.app";

    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            if (myProperties == null) {
                myProperties = new MyProperties(getApplicationContext());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while instantiating properties.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        String propertyValue = getPropertyValue();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "property value: '" + propertyValue + "'");
    }

    private String getPropertyValue() {
        String propertyValue = myProperties.getProperty(MyProperties.PROPERTY_NAME);
        if (propertyValue == null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Property '"+ MyProperties.PROPERTY_NAME+"' not set.");
            myProperties.setProperty(MyProperties.PROPERTY_NAME, "propertyValue");
            propertyValue = myProperties.getProperty(MyProperties.PROPERTY_NAME);
        }
        return propertyValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Stopping");
        myProperties.close();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

My app logs at startup which show that the properties file is empty, the property `propertyName` is initially not set and then it *is* set to `propertyValue`:

```
2021-03-29 07:40:36.561 9696-9696/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-03-29 07:40:36.563 9696-9696/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-03-29 07:40:36.664 9696-9696/? I/my.app: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-03-29 07:40:38.475 9696-9696/my.app I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-03-29 07:40:38.733 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.733 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.733 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.733 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.733 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.756 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: config file exists: true
2021-03-29 07:40:38.758 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Properties file start
2021-03-29 07:40:38.758 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Properties file end
2021-03-29 07:40:38.791 9696-9696/my.app I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> com.android.internal.policy.MultiWindowDecorSupport@6ed79bb, isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2021-03-29 07:40:38.791 9696-9696/my.app D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0
2021-03-29 07:40:38.888 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2021-03-29 07:40:38.893 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2021-03-29 07:40:39.034 9696-9725/my.app W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2021-03-29 07:40:39.036 9696-9727/my.app I/my.app: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6682(1333KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 51% free, 1471KB/2MB, paused 1.108ms total 110.073ms
2021-03-29 07:40:39.475 9696-9696/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:40:39.609 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Fetching property 'propertyName' with value 'null'.
2021-03-29 07:40:39.609 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Property 'propertyName' not set.
2021-03-29 07:40:39.609 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Setting property 'propertyName' to 'propertyValue'.
2021-03-29 07:40:39.610 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Fetching property 'propertyName' with value 'propertyValue'.
2021-03-29 07:40:39.610 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: property value: 'propertyValue'
...
```

Then I move the app to the background by pressing the Home button. Then I press the Overview button and select my app. Here are the logs showing that the property is still set:

```
...
2021-03-29 07:40:46.848 9696-9696/my.app D/ViewRootImpl@de343f7[MainActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
2021-03-29 07:40:46.864 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: Fetching property 'propertyName' with value 'propertyValue'.
2021-03-29 07:40:46.864 9696-9696/my.app D/my.app: property value: 'propertyValue'
...
```

Then I close the app (press Overview button, swipe up on app). When I restart the app, the properties are read from the properties file but the `propertyName` property doesn't seem to be loaded correctly even though it's read from the file:

```
<restart my.app>

2021-03-29 07:42:02.170 10196-10196/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-03-29 07:42:02.174 10196-10196/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-03-29 07:42:02.182 10196-10196/? I/my.app: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-03-29 07:42:03.444 10196-10196/my.app I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-03-29 07:42:03.597 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.598 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.598 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.598 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.598 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.615 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: config file exists: true
2021-03-29 07:42:03.617 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Properties file start
2021-03-29 07:42:03.617 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: #Mon Mar 29 07:40:44 GMT+02:00 2021
2021-03-29 07:42:03.617 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: propertyName=propertyValue
2021-03-29 07:42:03.618 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Properties file end
2021-03-29 07:42:03.642 10196-10196/my.app I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> com.android.internal.policy.MultiWindowDecorSupport@6ed79bb, isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2021-03-29 07:42:03.643 10196-10196/my.app D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0
2021-03-29 07:42:03.718 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.722 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2021-03-29 07:42:03.846 10196-10205/my.app W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2021-03-29 07:42:04.076 10196-10196/my.app W/my.app: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2021-03-29 07:42:04.178 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Fetching property 'propertyName' with value 'null'.
2021-03-29 07:42:04.178 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Property 'propertyName' not set.
2021-03-29 07:42:04.178 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Setting property 'propertyName' to 'propertyValue'.
2021-03-29 07:42:04.178 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: Fetching property 'propertyName' with value 'propertyValue'.
2021-03-29 07:42:04.179 10196-10196/my.app D/my.app: property value: 'propertyValue'
```

Comment: This is Android and not desktop Java - therefore, use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I've updated the first paragraph to reference the Android documentation which lead me down the path I took. I'd still like to understand where I went wrong while trying to follow the Android documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are reading data from file with `BufferedReader`, but `line` variable is just logged in loop, it isn't restoring data through `setProperty` or other parsing call. `Property` class is fulfiled at start with value and kept in memory as long as your app lives (so stays untouched during home/back to), but after killing it memory is cleaned up and next entrance is just printing stored values, isn't mapping them to `Property` object

check out official [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) - there is a table in there with possibilities and it seems like you should use [`App Preferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) link, which is pointing on [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), very similar approach to yours, but probably more efficient (use `apply()` instead of `commit()`)

edit: due to comments we've found some wrong stream usage (one multiple times) related to earlier logging with reading it, next trying to pass it to parsing method of data object

Comment: Thank, I'll take a look at that as an alternate way to do what I need. However, I'd still like to know why my original approach didn't work as opposed to trying a different way to skin the cat

Comment: I was just using the `BufferedReader` to show the contents of the properties file. But I'm passing a `FileInputStream` for the same file to the `load` method of `Properties` and my expectation is that doing this would set the properties recorded in the file. But, even though I "load" the properties, the `propertyName` property has no value in memory once the file is loaded. That's the crux of my question.

Comment: looks like `properties.load(inputStream);` is failing, inspect that method (you didn't posted source code of this class). note that this is stream, so when you read it (for logging purposes) then it may be empty (at the end of stream) for next usage. try your code without logging (comment this section, keep stream untouched until `load` method call) or try `properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile));`, but it would best to keep one instance and logging inside `load` method after each param read

Comment: btw. good practise is to `close` and `null`ify stream after usage, so technically you should call `close` right after logging in `while(line !=null)` loop, then `load` method would throw some exception according to (probably) read try from closed/`null` stream. don't keep references to stream class-available, close them and destroy right after usage

Comment: `properties` is an instance of `java.util.Properties` and the bug was more likely to be in my code than `Properties`. I refactored my code a bit to resolve the concerns you had around the streams and it's working. I'm not sure precisely where the issue was because just closing and re-instantiating the streams didn't fix it. But it's working now after fiddling with the streams. If you leave an answer pointing out the dodgy stream usage I'll accept that as the answer. And thanks!

Comment: added small edit, but I think that more value is in our comments. still glad I've helped, good luck :)